# Why the term "memory" instead of "RAM" is used in context of loading libraries?

Tags: memory, ram, loader, dynamic-linking, lib

I am a bit confused, most articles say that programs and libraries are loaded into "memory" or "main memory". I don't fully understand what "main memory" is. I thought it was "RAM", but some comments on the forums said it was wrong.
So, my questions:

- How to understand the term "memory" in this context
- Is it difference between "main memory" and "RAM"?
- Is it correct to say dynamic libraries are loaded into RAM?

Comment: Look up "virtual memory", which explains how modern OS'es deal with memory, and which will explain why "memory" isn't the same as "RAM".

Comment: RAM is an acronym for “random access memory”.